# C programming language

Tags: c

Codeblocks is asking me for an extra input than required after my first input it prompts for another input without the print statement that gets printed for every input prompt.

```
#include <stdio.h>
//Computing marks and average of students using 2D arrays
void main()
{
    int i,j,sum,marks[3][5];
    float avg;
    printf("Program to compute average marks of 3 students.\n");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {   for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        printf("Enter marks for student %d in subject %d:\t",i+1,j+1);
        scanf("%d ",&marks[i][j]);
    }
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            sum=sum+marks[i][j];
        }
        avg= sum/5.0;
        printf("The average marks of student %d is %f:\n",i+1,avg);
         }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `void main`'s most probably **wrong**.

Comment: Please change the title, and remove the codeblocks tag: this question is nothing to do with CodeBlocks.

Answer (score 2):

Problem in code :
Your format string like `scanf("%d ",&marks[i][j]);` requires whitespace after input which causes anomaly.

Corrected Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
//Computing marks and average of students using 2D arrays
int main()
{
    int i,j,sum = 0,marks[3][5];
    float avg;

    printf("Program to compute average marks of 3 students.\n");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("Enter marks for student %d in subject %d:\t",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",&marks[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            sum=sum+marks[i][j];
        }
        avg= sum/5.0;
        printf("The average marks of student %d is %f:\n",i+1,avg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

as specification says

> Number,order and type of conversion specifications must match the
>   number,order and type of parameters in the list

. Otherwise, the result will be unpredictable and may terminate input/output function.

Answer (score 2):

The format string in *scanf* should be `"%d"` (without a space). You have also forgotten to initialize the *sum* variable. Below is a corrected version of your code including a convenient array length macro. Hope this helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN(arr) (sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr)[0])

/*Computing marks and average of students using 2D arrays*/

int main()
{
    int i, j, sum, marks[3][5], count;
    float avg;

    printf("Program to compute average marks of 3 students.\n");
    for (i = 0; i < LEN(marks); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < LEN(marks[0]); j++) {
            printf("Enter marks for student %d in subject %d:\t", i + 1, j + 1);
            count = scanf("%d", &marks[i][j]);
            if (count != 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < LEN(marks); i++) {
        sum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < LEN(marks[0]); j++) {
            sum = sum + marks[i][j];
        }
        avg = ((float) sum) / ((float) LEN(marks[0]));
        printf("The average marks of student %d is %f:\n", i + 1, avg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, `void main()` is bad: you should use `int main()` and end your program with `return 0;`

But the problem is simply caused by an unnecessary space in your input format at `"%d "`. This removes the problem:

```
    scanf("%d",&marks[i][j]);
```